# How to Revert Android Studio Giraffe's New Version Logcat to old version?

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated my Android studio Giraffe, but I want the old logcat is any way that I can use the old logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **File>Settings>Experimental** and uncheck **Enable new Logcat tool window**

Comment: But there is no such option on Android Studio Giraffe